# How is "while (a%5)" and "while (5)" not a syntax error?

Tags: c++

Many times while solving problems I come across this particular condition inside a while loop:

```
while(a%5)
    statement;
```

or something like

```
while(5)
    statement;
```

At first I thought this was some kind of printing error or syntax error. But when I tried the program it worked perfectly!! How does it work?

Comment: Which part of it did you think would error? We can't really answer until we know what your expectation was and why!

Comment: while(1) is idiomatic when coding an infinite loop. Maybe the author got bored and decided to use while(5) instead? The net result is the same.

Comment: This is called a [Contextual conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion)

Answer (score 6):

Integers different than zero are truthy in C++

Answer (score 4):

**Non-zero integers in a conditional evaluate to true**

**zero as an integer in a conditional evaluates to false**

Why?  The compiler is simply casting the conditional's expression to a boolean.

The `while(expression)` conditional's body is executed as long as `expression` evaluates to true.

The compiler attempts to cast the expression to a boolean.  Integers other than 0 cast to true while 0 casts to false.

As long as the expression results in a non-zero integer, the result will be true.

Problems arise if your expression does not have an implicit or explicit cast to boolean.  Also, problems occur if you do not understand the implicit cast of your expression.

For example, suppose you have the following code:

```
int a = 6;
while(a % 5) {
   std::cout << "a is " << a << std::endl;
   a--;
}
```

a%5 would evaluate to 1 at the start of the first loop and to 0 at the start of the second loop.  So, the body would not be evaluated on the second loop.

Answer (score 2):

This works because integer values can be converted to boolean values.  Section 7.14 of the [C++17 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) states:

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to
>   member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool . **A zero value,
>   null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to false
>   ; any other value is converted to true.** For direct-initialization
>   (11.6), a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t can be converted to a prvalue
>   of type bool ; the resulting value is false .

So an integer value of 0 is considered false while any other integer value is considered true.

In the case of your example, `while(a%5)` means the loop will execute as long as `a` is not divisible by 5.  For `while(5)`, this will be an infinite loop.

Comment: FWIW, you might want to link to the C++17 standard since that is the active standard for the C++ tag right now.  You can get html links to the other standards as: https://github.com/timsong-cpp/cppwp

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks.  Updated to reflect C++17.